# Excel how to fill all selected blank cells with text

Tags: excel

Is it possible to select all the bank cells in an excel sheet and put the same value in all the cells?

I just want to populate them with "null"

I have Excel student 2010

Comment: Cntrl+H (Find and Replace), leave 'Find What' blank and change 'Replace With' to NULL. That should replace all blank cells in the USED range with NULL

Comment: @astander , I suggest you post this as an answer

Comment: Alternatively, you can use "Find & Select", "Go to special", "Blanks". Then with all blank cells selected, write null and enter with [Ctrl]+[Enter]. This (ctrl+Enter) will enter the same data (null) in all selected cells.

Comment: @brettdj, will do so shortly X-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

OK, what you can try is

**Cntrl+H** (Find and Replace), leave **Find What** blank and change **Replace With** to NULL.

That should replace all blank cells in the USED range with NULL

Answer (score 43):

To put the same text in a certain number of cells do the following:

1. Highlight the cells you want to put text into
2. Type into the cell you're currently in the data you want to be repeated
3. Hold Crtl and press 'return'

You will find that all the highlighted cells now have the same data in them.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Not ideal for what the OP is looking for, but very useful otherwise.

Comment: I think this should have been voted as the current answer. It essentially allows me to select subranges within used range and apply a common value to it. The answer marked as right does not allow that - I would call it a hack or workaround in the absence of this capability mentioned above.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a tricky way to do this - select the cells that you want to replace and in Excel 2010 select F5 to bring up the "goto" box. Hit the "special" button. Select "blanks" - this should select all the cells that are blank. Enter NULL or whatever you want in the formula box and hit ctrl + enter to apply to all selected cells. Easy!

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer to this question. The accepted answer will do what OP asked across either the sheet or the workbook, but doesn't have the granularity to work on just a single column (which was my use-case here).

Comment: This does seem to be even more fine tuned than the previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

If all the cells are under one column, you could just filter the column and then select "(blank)" and then insert any value into the cells. But be careful, press "alt + 4" to make sure you are inserting value into the visible cells only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe search and replace will do it for you (doesn't work for me in Excel 2010 Home). Are you sure you want to put "null" in EVERY cell in the sheet? That is millions of cells, in which case there is no way a search and replace would be able to handle it memory-wise (correct me if I am wrong).

In the case I am right and you don't want millions of "null" cells, then here is a macro. It asks you to select the range then put "null" inside every cell that was blank.

```vb
Sub FillWithNull()

Dim cell As range
Dim myRange As range

Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select the range", Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In myRange
    If Len(cell) = 0 Then
        cell.Value = "Null"
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The Cntl+H should work only on the UsedRange. It worked fine for me with xl07

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in VBA, then this is a shorter method:

```
Sub FillBlanksWithNull()

'This macro will fill all "blank" cells with the text "Null"

'When no range is selected, it starts at A1 until the last used row/column

'When a range is selected prior, only the blank cell in the range will be used.

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "Null"

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

MsgBox "No blank cells found", vbDefaultButton1, Error

Resume Next

End Sub
```

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: Even smaller in one line: Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "Null"

Comment: this is very efficient, but 'SpecialCells' is best used after 'On Error Resume Next' (then an 'On Error Goto 0' as the code will error out if SpecialCells is Nothing. SpecialCells(xlBlanks) won't pick up a fornula evaluating to "". +1 btw

Comment: Brett, Thank you for your improvement idea with the On Error addition. I was too focused on reducing the code.